# Enforce explicit (direct) #include statements with GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I am wondering if it is possible to enforce direct #include requirements with GCC. Let say I have these files:

abc.h:

```
typedef struct {
   int useful;
} str;
```

file1.h:

```
#include <abc.h>
#ifndef GUARD
#define GUARD

#include <deh.h>

typedef struct {
   int useful;
} str2;

#endif
```

file2.h:

```
#ifndef GUARD2
#define GUARD2
#include <file1.h>

void a_function (str*  my_str);
void a_function2(str2* my_str);

#endif
```

The problem is that "file2.h" is using "str" defined in "abc.h". Let say "file1.h" is provided by the system on some Linux systems. I have no control of "file1.h" content. If may or may not include , it may or may not be inside include guards and it may or may not change over time.

The issue is when it come to support multiple distributions and system. If file2.h is accidentally using "str" without including , it may compile anyway on most systems, but may fail on others, or in the future when "file1.h" change.

Is there a way to force GCC (or LLVM) to use only types directly defined in file2.h? I understand that "#include" are just that, includes, so the compiler internal may not be aware of those issues after the preprocessor phase, however, I am wondering if this is currently possible and, if so, how?

I had this problem a few time with "normal" Linux distributions, but it was even worst with early Android NDK versions.

Comment: Well, why don't you include abc.h first?

Comment: Better still, `file2.h` should `#include` nothing. I find this question unclear. *What do you want the compiler to do in this case?*

Comment: @Beta: There definitely is not consensus on the "flatten includes and put them all in the primary source file" approach.  Is that what you are advocating?

Comment: @zneak: The question is about when developers forget to include all required files. In some cases, because they are indirectly included, it will compile anyway, so the developer wont notice. This cause problems when indirectly included files are included by files that are out of your control. In those case, it may induce a compilation error when the third party owner of the said file change it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, I'm saying that omitting (not expanding) `#include` statements is a sensible way to achieve the OP's stated goal.

Answer (score 2):

No, `#include` instructs the compiler to treat the other file's content as if it were placed at the `#include` directive -- you're asking for the other file's content to be treated somehow differently.

Your best hope in this scenario is to use a static analysis tool that performs dependency analysis, and check that there are no direct dependencies on types (or functions or objects) obtained through indirect (nested) inclusion.

The free [doxygen](http://doxygen.org) documentation tool extracts information about inclusion and dependencies, which it makes available in XML format.  Of course, it isn't as accurate as a true compiler, in terms of overload resolution and template processing.  I'm sure there are paid tools that will be more accurate (user Ira Baxter pops up from time to time mentioning a commercial product his company sells, DMS Toolkit or something like that, which sounded like it would get at this information).  But I'm guessing that doxygen will give you the right results for most "normal" code.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything in the C++ language which would verify that all headers are included correctly. However, there is [include-what-you-use](http://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/) which is based on [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). I haven't tried using it but it seems to be in the direction of what you are looking for. For C, implementing an analyzer detecting dependencies and report missing direct includes seems to be fairly straight forward. When trying the same with C++ things get somewhat harder due to the need of detecting dependencies for template instantiations.

Based on last weeks discussion at the C++ committee meeting, refactoring sources and headers to properly include what is actually used may be helpful for future [module support](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) in C++.

Comment: "The main goal of include-what-you-use is... replacing `#include`s with forward-declares when possible"  Not sure that is what this question calls for, or even a good idea.  There are advantages to using forward declarations, but they are a form of code duplication and one must take care to not break the One Definition Rule when using them.

Comment: OTOH I'm sure that include-what-you-use is a good foundation for the static analysis this question requires.  Probably just not usable as-is.